# OpenVPN bridge network from routed clients

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn

I have the following setup:

- **subnet 1** - `10.0.1.0/24` with a machine used as NAT and also running an OpenVPN client
- **subnet 2** - `192.168.1/24` with an OpenVPN server (the server in subnet 1 connect here)
- **subnet 3** - `10.0.2.0/24` that uses the NAT machine (subnet 1) to access the internet, so all non-local traffic is routed there to the `eth0` interface

The OpenVPN client creates the `tun0` interface and appropriate routing so that I can access machines from `192.168.1/24`

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-208 ~]# telnet 192.168.1.186 8081
Trying 192.168.1.186...
Connected to 192.168.1.186.
Escape character is '^]'.

[root@ip-10-0-1-208 ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.5        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.5        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
169.254.169.254 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     10.8.0.5        255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 tun0
```

However, when I try the same from **subnet 3**, it can't reach that machine.

```
[root@ip-10-0-2-61 ~]# telnet 192.168.1.186 8081
Trying 192.168.1.186...
```

I suspect that it's because **subnet 3** is routed to `eth0` on the NAT machine in **subnet 1** and it cannot jump to `tun0`.

What's the easiest way to resolve it? I don't want to use iptables. I can't change the routing from machines in **subnet 1** because it's done in AWS and so it works only with specific interfaces. Also, the NAT machine gets its IP with DHCP and so bridging is a bit complicated.

IP forwarding is set on the NAT machine

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-208 ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Frankly, if you want a proper answer, you should include the following information: the list of all IP addresses & the routing tables of all affected hosts: the two clients (the working & the non-working), the OpenVPN server, the NAT machine, and any extra IP routers in between them.

Comment: A little drawing of your network may help!

Comment: This seem to be a `simple` routing problem. You have to inform each host about which one act as a *gateway* or use *nat*...

Comment: It would help to know wich iptables rule you used to do NAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can not change the routing on subnet 1 and do not want to use iptables one approach would be to create a vpn tunnel from subnet 3 to subnet 2 directly.

In case your gateways for subnet 3 and subnet 2 are linux servers I would use openvpn as well. If it is a firewall device, then create a vpn tunnel using the firewall's software to talk to the firewall of subnet 2.

Of course with iptables and the ability to change routing on subnet 1 the fixes are far more flexible, let me know if you like a solution in that regard.